# При установки Linux Ubuntu в Virtual Box есть вопрос «стереть диск и установить Ubuntu», я выделил часть раздела ...?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

При установки Linux Ubuntu в Virtual Box есть вопрос "стереть диск и установить Ubuntu", у меня раздел в виндовсь, где в нем есть место свободное, часть раздела на виндовсе свободна, а вторая часть с файлами. Я правильно понимаю, что те 20 гигабайт, которые я выделил для виртуальной машины Ubuntu, они заполнят свободное место в резделе виндовс, и мои остальные файлы не сотрутся на разделе. Или нужно создать в Windows отдельный раздел под виртуальную машину, и туда coхранить и создать виртуальную машину ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

для виртуальной машины создан отдельный файл, который не затрагивает другое пространство. Его можно хоть как использовать, ничего из остального не пострадает.